# Increment and decrements numbers

Tags: search, vim, numbers, increment, decrement

I have this text with numbers:

```
My numbers are 04, and 0005
My numbers are 05, and 0006
My numbers are 06, and 0035
My numbers are 07, and 0007
My numbers are 08, and 0009
```

This is the code I always used to increment or decrement numbers in a selection/block selection/column:
p.e. increment the last 4 numbers in above text with 8:

```
 '<,'>s/\%V\<\d\{4}\>/\=submatch(0)+8/g
```

but I noted today that it does strange things.
This is the output:

```
My numbers are 04, and 13
My numbers are 05, and 14
My numbers are 06, and 37 <---
My numbers are 07, and 15
My numbers are 08, and 17
```

- it removes the leading zero's ( I would like to keep them if there are leading zero's
  and not add them if there aren't leading zero's)
- it added 8 to all numbers except 37, where it added 2. (why?)

Can anyone help me ***to find a regex to add /subtract numbers
from selection (or block selection) without losing the leading zero's***?

note:
I noted that Control A + Control x keeps the leading zero's and does the work as I want but:
- I've seen that it can not be used in a substitute command ('<,'>s/)
- and I don't know how to add p.e. 200 to a list of numbers (200 x ?)

Comment: If it's any help, the way I prefer to do stuff like this is to write an external filter (eg, in perl), then use !/path/filter.pl on the block.  This makes problems easier to solve, and the filters are easy to reuse and modify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

leading zero makes number `8-based`.

```
(0035)8 == (29)10
```

You can test in vim:

```
:echo 0035 == 29
```

It'll print `1`(true).

---

Try this:

```
:%s/\(\<[0-9]\{4}\>\)\@=0*\([0-9]*\)/\=submatch(2)+8/
```

Comment: "@Kev, I checked your regex. It works fine but I noted that it doesn't consider numbers when it is attached to a text character p.e. text22text or 22text. What do I have to change to make that work? (btw I suppose that it is not possible with a submatch regex to keep leading zero's isn't it?)

Answer (score 2):

this?

```
:%s/\v[0-9]{4}/\=printf("%04d", substitute(submatch(0), '^0\+', '', 0)+8)/
```

**EDIT**

@Remonn, you should give the right sample input in your question. the line above works on your example.

for your new requirement, take a look the line below:

input:

```
40
20
120
0500
230
0000000020
00000000000005000
```

vim cmd:

```
:%!awk '{if($0~/^0/){f="\%"length($0)"d";$0+=8; s=sprintf(f,$0); gsub(/ /,"0",s);}else s=$0+8;print s}'
```

will change the file to:

```
48
28
128
0508
238
0000000028
00000000000005008
```

in my cmd, I used '%', you can select (v) the numbers you want to do tricks with, then try with my cmd.

good luck

Comment: Thank you Kent, nice regex. However I noted that it put also for digits without leading zero's, leading zero's. I would like to keep the leading zero's if there are and not add them if there are not (as C-A / C-X does).

Comment: take these numbers: `40, 20, 120, 0500, 230` - above regex gives wrong results. Output: `48, 28, 200, 1300, 310`

Comment: "@Kent  I spoke about a general regex in my question :) Thanks for the awk. It works fine. I'll keep it. However awk does not change the @/ numbers within in the text as kev's regex does. (Btw ho do you guys add the @Name before the comment?)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Vim treats numbers beginning with `0` as octal.

For this reason I have this in my .vimrc:

```
set   nrformats-=octal  " Don't bother with octal, I never use it
```

Comment: Hi Johnsyweb, I checked this but it didn't change anything.