# Vim incorrectly removes zeros when decrementing

Tags: vim

Vim removes zeros from in front of some digits when decrementing:

If I take a text file with the following:

```
a02 
a03
a04
a05
a06
a07
a08
a09  
a10
a11
```

And use `ctrl+V` to highlight the second and third columns, and then hit `ctrl+X` to decrement, I am left with:

```
a01
a02
a03
a04
a05
a06
a7
a8
a9
a10
```

I am running Vim version 7.4.1689 and I loaded it without my .vimrc via

```
$ vim -u NONE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because Vim will automatically recognize and convert octal values.

From the help (`:h variables`):

> Conversion from a Number to a String is by making the ASCII representation of
>   the Number.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>    Number 123      -->     String "123"
>    Number 0        -->     String "0"
>    Number -1       -->     String "-1"
> ```
>
> Conversion from a String to a Number is done by converting the first digits to
>   a number.  Hexadecimal "0xf9", Octal "017", and Binary "0b10" numbers are
>   recognized.  If the String doesn't start with digits, the result is zero.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>    String "456"    -->     Number 456
>    String "6bar"   -->     Number 6
>    String "foo"    -->     Number 0
>    String "0xf1"   -->     Number 241
>    String "0100"   -->     Number 64
>    String "0b101"  -->     Number 5
>    String "-8"     -->     Number -8
>    String "+8"     -->     Number 0
> ```

Your values `02` through `07` are being recognized as valid octal values and preserved as such, decremented to octal `01` through `06`.

When you reach `08` it is not a valid octal value. It is treated as the string `08`, converted to decimal value `8`, and decremented to `7`. This happens again with `09`, which ends up being `8`.

The `10` and `11` values are decremented as decimal as well. Because `10` was decimal, not octal, you don't get a leading `0` in the resulting `9` value.

I'm not aware of a way to do what you want with the decrement command.

**EDIT:** After finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10195534/2449905), I tested this expression and it does what you are trying to do in this specific case:

```
:%s/\v[0-9]+/\=printf("%02d", substitute(submatch(0), '^0\+', '', 0)-1)/
```

I'm not sure whether this solves your general use case, because it's quite different from the original operation using a selection. But for the file you provided, it achieves the result you were after.

Dissecting this a bit to explain it:

First we start by calling the global sub command `%s` and passing the `\v` flag to turn on "very magic" mode. This may or may not change the behavior depending on your settings, but this is a public example, so it is included here to ensure that mode is active.

```
:%s/\v
```

Then, we find all the contiguous sequences of digits. This will find `02`, `03`, and so on from your example.

```
[0-9]+
```

Then in the replacement portion we have this command, which does the real work:

```
\=printf("%02d", substitute(submatch(0), '^0\+', '', 0)-1)
```

The `substitute()` function determines what the new value is. `submatch(0)` means to use the entire match. Using a pattern of `^0\+` and a replacement of (empty string) says to strip the leading zero from any number which has one. The `0` at the end isn't too important; it just says there are no flags to the `substitute()` function.

The result of the `substitute` command is a number. Say `02` has been stripped down to be `2`. Using the `- 1` at the end, we subtract 1 from that result (decrement).

Finally, this result is passed to the `printf` function. Using a format string `%02d` says to print the values as decimal, in 2-digit wide format, padding with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want Vim to treat all numbers as decimals, you may want to add the following line to your .vimrc:

```
set nrformats=
```

Comment: Or if it's a one-off case like for the OP, execute command `:set nrformats=` before using `Ctrl+X` rather than changing it forever with the .vimrc.